# How to create LIKE and UNLIKE button in jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I want to create LIKE and UNLIKE button in jquery, what i did is ,

```
 <span><a class="like-Unlike" href="">Like</a></span> |
   function LikeUnLikeButton() {
            $(".like-Unlike").click(function (e) {
                if ($(this).html() == "Like") {
                    $(this).html('Unlike');
                }
                else {
                    $(this).html('Like');
                }
            });
        }
```

but it is not working , problem is when i click on LIKE button i can see unlike button and again it's back to LIKE button

Please check it out here : http://jsfiddle.net/mHJnH/

Comment: put # inside href, href="#" so it wont continue to reload page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have miss placed closing parenthesis of `$(this`  **)** is missing here.

**Change**

```
  $(this.html('Unlike'));
```

**To**

```
 $(this).html('Unlike');
```

**Edit due to update in question**

You may not need function LikeUnLikeButton() {

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/pq2BY/)**

```
$(".like-Unlike").click(function(e) {
    if ($(this).html() == "Like") {
        $(this).html('Unlike');
    }
    else {
        $(this).html('Like');
    }
    return false;
});​
```

Comment: ok, i did mistake while write a question, i updated my question agian

Comment: Updated my answer with live demo

Comment: Also return false which I did or use preventDefault to stop the navigation behaviour. http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/

Answer (score 1):

You have some errors in your code

`$(this.html('Unlike'));`

should be

`$(this).html('Unlike');`

same is the case for

`$(this.html('Like'));`

should be

`$(this).html('Like');`

Answer (score 1):

You were almost there!

The following code works:

```
<span><a class="like-Unlike" href="#">Like</a></span>
<script>
function LikeUnLikeButton() {
            $(".like-Unlike").click(function (e) {
                if ($(this).html() == "Like") {
                    $(this).html('Unlike');
                }
                else {
                    $(this).html('Like');
                }
            });
        }
LikeUnLikeButton();
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this out. 
http://jsfiddle.net/fedmich/DTAbj/

I suggest you cache your $(this) so it will be faster.
then use the $.data to store if its liked, rather than just using .html() to match the string.

```
$(function() {
$('.like-button').click(function(){
    var obj = $(this);
    if( obj.data('liked') ){
        obj.data('liked', false);
        obj.html('Like');
    }
    else{
        obj.data('liked', true);
        obj.html('Unlike');
    }
});
});​
```

Answer (score 0):

instead of `$(this).html() == "Like"`  use `$(this).val() == "Like"`
so as to access the value of the button instead of the whole html code.
thus when changing the value use `$(this).val("Like")` or  `$(this).val("Unlike")`

Answer (score 0):

You should use e.preventDetault to prevent anchor tag action. And you can use toggleClass and hasClass to identify instead of comparing plain text.

```js
$('.action').on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var anchorLink = $(this);
    anchorLink.toggleClass('like');
    var text = anchorLink.hasClass('like') ? 'Like' : 'UnLike'
    anchorLink.text(text);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class="action like">Like</a>
```